# sitemap not generating correctly in mysql database driven PHP website

Tags: php, sitemap

I am working on one dictionary based site working fine but when i try to generate sitemap using http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ it is showing only domain base url but i have more urls in site. i have prepared sitemap using php it is showing all urls correctly when i browse with in my site. please help how to solve this problem.

in my htaccess i have created as

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]`

site name http://dictionary.vikrams.com

sitemap url is dictionary.vikrams.com/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0):

in your site, some of the links are not direct links. some of the links uses **#** for pointing to a part of page....

http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/  tracks only the direct links in your sites.....

```
 <a href="#" tabindex="5">Grammar</a></li><li class="responsive_hide_on_smartphone responsive_hide_on_tablet">

 <a href="#" tabindex="6">Spoken English</a></li><li class="responsive_hide_on_smartphone responsive_hide_on_tablet">

 <a href="#" tabindex="7">Dictionaries</a></li><li class="responsive_hide_on_smartphone responsive_hide_on_tablet">

 <a href="#" tabindex="8">Contact</a></li><li class="responsive_hide_on_smartphone responsive_hide_on_tablet">
```

these are some links from your page, its href="#". it will not be treated as a link by

**xml-sitemaps.com**

Comment: Yes you are correct but my question about dictionary.vikrams.com/sitemap.xml urls not taking.

Comment: sitemap generation only track the links on your page, it will not track any directories in your root folder...

Comment: Ok, did you check sitemap.xml in my site, i am talking about that why it is not taking is any changes i should do to take those urls coming from php,mysql and i need to index them also.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your htaccess file code and it seems to be OK. I have further checked this by implementing the same on my local development server. I would like to share that it seems to working as per your expectations. I would prefer if you can check for mod rewrite is allow where you trying to make these changes. I hope the information will work for you.

Comment: First thanks for reply, mod rewrite was enabled in both local and remote servers. problem was database urls using mod rewrite not indexing by xml-sitemaps.com only static urls showing when i try to create sitemap, please check at http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ with domain name of dictionary.vikrams.com